# Escaping JSON to avoid changing the insert string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pg-promise

I have the following json string that should be inserted directly into the database in a single column:

```
const jsString = JSON.stringify({"escaping":"d\"on't"});

const insertion = [{"a":2,"json":jsString}];

const query = pgp.helpers.insert(insertion,["a","json"],"tbl");
```

however what actually ends up in the database is:

```
{"escaping":"d"on't"}
```

removing the escaping \ in d"on't and making the string invalid json. Is there some way to avoid this?

This would be beneficial since it would be nice if my valid json would remain so.

Comment: Try using double backslash there. Because single one is consumed by JavaScript itself.

Comment: actually make it triple, double to put single backslash into database and another one to escape doublequote in JS.

Comment: have you tried this `{"escaping":"d\\\"on't"}`? what is the string that you want to save? this code will save this {"escaping":"d\"on't"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't stringify your data into JSON, use it directly
2. Set column formatting as JSON, using `:json` modifier

```html
const data = {escaping: "d\"on't"};
const insertion = [{a:2, json:data}];
const query = pgp.helpers.insert(insertion, ["a", "json:json"], "tbl");
```

But if your `data` is always an object, then you don't even need to use the `:json` modifier, it will be automatically formatted as correct JSON.

For more details see the flexibility of the [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) type. You can manipulate your input data in every thinkable way.

Comment: But when inserting as objects d"on't still ends up in the database rather than d\"on't which would be needed in order for it to be valid json

Comment: @Bomaz What are you talking about? It writes and reads that kind of data just fine. I tested it locally.

Comment: When I test it locally I get d\"on't in the query. However since sql uses the \ to escape the " what needs to be in the query should probably be d\\\"on't since in order for it to be valid JSON what should be in the database is: 
{"escaping":"d\"on't"} and sql itself consumes the \ if it isn't turned into \\\

Comment: @Bomaz, no, you got it wrong somehow. I don't know what data or where you are looking at, but I have a real test where such data is being written and read back correctly. I hope you are not just looking at some query editor and making assumptions here. Test you the read/write properly. You will get back exactly what you wrote into the database.

Comment: When I run the following: pgp.helpers.insert([{"a":{"test":"d\"on't"}}], ["a:json"],"tmp") 

The generated query is: INSERT INTO "tmp"("a") VALUES('{"test":"d\"on''t"}') 

Unfortunately this means that what ends up in the database is the string {"test":"d"on't"} due to sql stripping the \ so it gets turned into invalid json. In order to become properly escaped json wouldn't the query have to be 
 INSERT INTO "tmp"("a") VALUES('{"test":"d\\\"on''t"}')?
Since currently my js object becomes invalid json

Comment: What makes you think that this is invalid JSON?

Comment: Because the string that ends up in the database is {"test":"d"on't"} which is invalid according to http://jsonlint.com/ due to SQL stripping the \

Comment: Apologies, I found the issue, I was using AWS redshift and it behaves differently compared to postgres for the same insertion query. So pg-promise is not to blame for my problems. 

Differences between redshift and postgres are.

Comment: @Bomaz I knew it, because too many people work with JSON via pg-promise, and nobody complains :)

Answer (score 0):

This string in js `const jsString = JSON.stringify({"escaping":"d\\\"on't"});` will result in this `{"escaping":"d\\\"on't"}`

While this string in js `const jsString = JSON.stringify({"escaping":"don't"});` will result in this `{"escaping":"don't"}`

Comment: But I would like to avoid implementing manual escaping of the string. I get it from elsewhere and just insert it into the db. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Is not so bad to replace by using regex. Here is an example:
 `var str = "your \"weird\\\" string";
str = str.replace(/[\\"]/g, function (x){return "\\"+x;});
`

Comment: if this helps you, please let me know, so I will edit my answer for you